# Python Matrix of Objects - Defining Attributes

Tags: python, matrix, pygame

I have created a matrix of objects using the following code:

```py
class Tiles:

    def __init__(self, char="", blocked=False):
        self.char = char
        self.blocked = blocked

row = [Tiles()] * grid_width
matrix = [list(row) for i in range(grid_height)]
```

I then render the list contents using Pygame's render method as below:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for j, tile in enumerate(row):
        text = game_font.render(Tiles().char, True, [255, 255, 255])
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (j * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2), i * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2))
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

I would like to define the .char attribute for all indexes that require a difference character to the default. I am unsure how to do this.

So, how would I go about changing the character of individual indices at will and, also, is this the best logical approach?

Comment: Waht do you mean by *"I would like to define the .char attribute for all indexes that require a difference character"*? Do you want to define a list of index tuples (i, j) which are associated to different `.char` attribute?

Comment: I am a beginner so I may get the terminology badly wrong. Ultimately, the matrix is rendered to display a game map of strings and/or integers. I would like to be able to set each matrix entry using the char attribute. I will also need to use other attributes for the matrix entries in future, such as colour.

Comment: You've got the same `Tiles` instance in every cell of your matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to crate a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which associates a character to an index tuple:

```py
charmap = {(0, 1) : 'A', (2, 5) : 'B', (3, 4) : 'C'}
```

The above map associates `A` to the row 0 and column 1, `B` to the row 2 and column 5 and `C` to the row 3 and column 4.

A character can be get from the location `(i, j)` by [`.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict) where the 1st parameter is the key and the 2nd parameter is the default value. Get a character at an arbitrary location (i, j) and else "" by:

```py
c = charmap.get((i, j), "")
```

Use this to generate the matrix:

```py
matrix = [[Tiles(charmap.get((i, j), "")) 
          for j in range(grid_width)] for i in range(grid_height)]
```

---

Alternatively you can predefine tiles for certain positions:

```
tilemap = {(0, 1) : Tiles('A'), (2, 5) : Tiles('B'), (3, 4) : Tiles('C')}
matrix = [[tilemap.get((i, j), Tiles())
          for j in range(grid_width)] for i in range(grid_height)]
```

In both case you can render the tiles by 2 nested loops, but note in the loop you've to access the `Tiles` object form the matrix by `tile.char`. `Tiles().char` would create an entire new object:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
  for j, tile in enumerate(row):
      text = game_font.render(tile.char, True, [255, 255, 255])
      text_rect = text.get_rect()
      text_rect.center = (j * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2), i * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2))
      screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

---

To simplify things, I recommend to add a `draw` mehtod to the class `Tiles`. This makes this makes it easier to handle additional attributes like a color:

```py
class Tiles:

    def __init__(self, char="", color=(255, 255, 255), blocked=False):
        self.char = char
        self.color = color
        self.blocked = blocked

    def draw(self):
        text = game_font.render(self.char, True, self.color)
        text_rect = text.get_rect()
        text_rect.center = (j * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2), i * TILESIZE + (TILESIZE // 2))
        screen.blit(text, text_rect)
```

Specif the individual tiles:

```py
tilemap = {
    (0, 1) : Tiles('A', (255, 0, 0)),
    (2, 5) : Tiles('B', (0, 255, 0)),
    (3, 4) : Tiles('C', (0, 0, 255))}

matrix = [[tilemap.get((i, j), Tiles())
          for j in range(grid_width)] for i in range(grid_height)]
```

Call the draw method in the nested loops:

```py
for i, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for j, tile in enumerate(row):
        tile.draw()
```

Comment: I have used your first example and it works. I don't fully understand exactly what is going on so I will study matrixes and dictionaries in greater detail. How would I add further attributes? Change colours independently etc?

Comment: Thanks ever so much. Works just how I'd hoped.

Comment: Wow, that is so helpful. I am in your debt. The only part I don't understand is the tilemap.get(). Is .get() a built in Python method for accessing data from structures?

Comment: Perfect, thanks for all your assistance. I will get some studying done. If I could give you more karma I would!

Comment: As an extended question, when I access a Tiles object from the dictionary using the key I don't seem to be able to reference an attribute. I am storing the player position in a tuple and when it matches the key tuple I want something to happen relating to the rect attribute. But it says the object does not have a rect attribute?

Comment: @MartinJones It `Tiles` has a `.rect` attribute (`self.rect`), then you can do `tilemap[(i, j)].rect` or even `tilemap.get((i, j), Tiles()).rect`, respectively  `matrix[j][i].rect` and of course in the inner `for` loop you can access the rectangle by  `tile.rect`

Comment: So, the tilemap[(i, j)].rect produces a key error when trying to store in a new variable. Is it because the rect attribute is defined in the draw method and is not a Class variable?

Comment: @MartinJones No, `tilemap[(i, j)].rect` is valid, if `(i, j)` is in tilemap. In the example in the answer just (0, 1), (2. 5) and (3, 4) are in the map. All other combinations generate key errors. But you an get the `Tiles` objects by `matrix[i][j].rect`. Note the same 3 objects wiche are in `tilemap` are in `matrix`, too. But `matrix` additionally contains objects for all the other tiles

Comment: `player_pos = (player.y // TILESIZE, player.x // TILESIZE)
    test = tilemap.get((player_pos), "Empty")

    if test is not "Empty":
        print(test.rect)` This causes a 'Tiles object has no rect attribute' error.

Comment: @MartinJones So the issue is in the class `Tiles`. Do you init `self.rect` in the constructor of tiles?

Comment: No the rect only exists in the draw method.

Comment: @MartinJones So that's the issue. The object just has no attribute `.rect`. Set an initial attribute `self.rect` in the constructor and update the attribute in the `draw` method. So each object has the attribute `.rect` at any time.

Comment: Thanks for giving me your time today, Ive genuinely appreciated it. Ive learnt so much with your input.